# XML Parsing in phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xml-parsing, windows-phone-7.1

How to parse the elements of only Main_Screen node in the below XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<plist version="1.0">
<Main_Screen>
        <row>
            <btn_name>Buyer Programs</btn_name>

        </row>
        <row>
            <btn_name>Seller�s Programs</btn_name>

        </row>
<Main_Screen>
<Buyer>
       <row>
           <btn_name>buy_bac</btn_name>

       </row>
       <row>
           <btn_name>buy_hme</btn_name>

     </row>
<Buyer>
<Seller>
   <row>
       <btn_name>buy_bac</btn_name>

   </row>
   <row>
       <btn_name>buy_hme</btn_name>

 </row>
<seller>
<Lender>
   <row>
       <btn_name>buy_bac</btn_name>

   </row>
   <row>
       <btn_name>buy_hme</btn_name>

 </row>
<lender>
<abcd>
   <row>
       <btn_name>buy_bac</btn_name>

   </row>
   <row>
       <btn_name>buy_hme</btn_name>

 </row>
<abcd>

</plist>
```

I tried the below code but all elements are getting parsed i want to parse only the elements below main_screen node,

```
 XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("HelpScreenData.xml");

        var data = (from query in loadedData.Descendants("row")

                    select new tutstat
                    {
                        btn_name = (string)query.Element("btn_name"),
                        strng = (string)query.Element("strng"),
                    }).ToList();
```

plz direct me,thank u!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it's as simple as using `Root.Element("Main_Screen")` before the call to `Descendants`:

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("HelpScreenData.xml");

var data = loadedData.Root
                     .Element("Main_Screen")
                     .Descendants("row") // Or .Elements("row")
                     .Select(x => new tutstat 
                             {
                                btn_name = (string) x.Element("btn_name"),
                                strng = (string) x.Element("strng"),
                             })
                     .ToList();
```

I've changed this from a query expression to a simple stack of method calls as the query expression was only adding noise.

You should also fix all your names to comply with .NET conventions and be more explanatory.

Comment: ,In the above if I want to parse elements under two nodes how I do that  for example) elements only below main_screen and buyer?

Comment: @yogesh: Well, you could use `Root.Elements("Main_Screen").Concat(Root.Elements("Buyer")).Descendants("Row")...`

Comment: @yogesh: It should be fine, it's part of LINQ to Objects. I'd have to see a concrete example to see what's wrong.

Comment: I tried Root.Elements("Main_Screen") doesnt have concat attribute.

Comment: @yogesh: It's not an attribute, it's an extension method.